# Override `extension_attributes.xml` in extending custom module (which targets ShippingInformationInterface/ShippingInformationExtension)

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, shipping-methods, extension-attributes

The question is specifically about `./Magento/Checkout/Api/Data/ShippingInformationExtension.php` and adding extra columns via `extension_attributes.xml`.

### Modules:

- Source module: `Vendor_Module`
- Overriding/extending module: `Vendor2_Module2` (extending JS / templates etc / Plugins) from Source module.

#### Issue

I need to use a custom `extension_attributes.xml` inside `Vendor2_Module2`.

#### Information

- The source file:

`Vendor_Module\etc\extension_attributes.xml`:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
     <extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface">
          <attribute code="pickup_store" type="string"/>
          <attribute code="pickup_date" type="string"/>
     </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

- Custom module that is overriding/using plugins and other customizations from source `Vendor_Module` module:

`Vendor2_Module2\etc\extension_attributes.xml`:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
     <extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface">
          <!-- trimmed (other attributes) that will be added here -->
          <!-- Custom data for this overridden module -->
          <attribute code="custom_shipping_method_title" type="string"/>
     </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

#### Findings

Running `bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento setup:di:compile` does not generate the extra attribute `custom_shipping_method_title` in the new overriding module's `ShippingInformationExtensionInterface`

```
namespace Magento\Checkout\Api\Data;

/**
 * ExtensionInterface class for @see \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface
 */
interface ShippingInformationExtensionInterface extends \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesInterface
{
    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getPickupStore();

    /**
     * @param string $pickupStore
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPickupStore($pickupStore);

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getPickupDate();

    /**
     * @param string $pickupDate
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPickupDate($pickupDate);
}
```

- *As indicated in generated/code/ file above, this only contains `getPickupStore()` and `getPickupDate()` (mapped via **`pickup_store`** and **`pickup_date`** respectively).*

#### Question

- *It is missing the new custom attribute **`custom_shipping_method_title`** , eg. `getCustomShippingMethodTitle()` entry in the generated code.*

How do I override / point Magento 2 to use `Vendor2_Module2\etc\extension_attributes.xml` instead of `Vendor_Module\`?

I know how to override / use plugins via `di.xml` for classes but since this is an XML file to be overridden, what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be misunderstanding how extension attributes work. You will not need to overwrite any extension attributes from the vendor module, rather, you can define your own extension attributes on the same entity within your own custom module. You can essentially copy the logic from the vendor module over to your custom module - changing the extension attribute code etc.

I recommend you have a thorough read-through of the following documentation, it provides quite a clear and comprehensive explanation of extension attributes and how to use them:

- https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/add-attributes/

Comment: Perhaps the information I provided was not clear, but please consider this:  `Vendor_Module` is a **third party module** that already contains `Vendor_Module::etc\extension_attributes.xml`; and I need additional fields in `Vendor2_Module2\etc\extension_attributes.xml` such that it 'appends/replaces' `Vendor_Module` attributes.   Before asking the question, I thought it should be possible to _override extension_attributes.xml_ in the way I attempted (this of course resulted in the missing field still).   I did not realise I would need to still use a Plugin for this, feels slightly restrictive.

Comment: Thank you for the reference!

Comment: @CvRChameleon I'm afraid you cannot override a specific `extension_attributes.xml` file - Magento will essentially just merge all these files together during compilation. If you want to append the data, it's probably best to use a plugin on the method that sets this data.